# split variant string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am looping through an output that has variations of the string

```
1.20.4.2  script1  get_pool  tim 3.15.08
1.20.5.1  script1  get_aggregate  bob 3.16.10
2.0.4  script2  get_aggregate, get_pool tim 3.16.10
2.0.5  script2  get_aggregate, get_pool, make_volume paul 3.24.10
```

i want to split into item, name, function, owner, and date. how do i capture all of the functions in the line knowing that there could there could a large or small set of functions per line?

i was able to deal with 1 or 2 functions, but then i ran across another with 3

```
if "," in line:
    (item , name, function1, function2, owner, date) = line.split()
    function1 = function1[:-1]
    function = ("|").join([function1, function2])
else:
    (item, name, function, owner, date) = line.split()
```

i am using using python 3.x

Comment: Please post the actual data instead.

Comment: Are the functions separated by commas, like your mock data suggests? Please provide a representative sample of the actual data.

Comment: i updated the data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

The pattern I see is that the functions always fall between the first two and the last two words.

I used slicing after splitting each line.

```
text = """1.20.4.2  script1  get_pool  tim 3.15.08
1.20.5.1  script1  get_aggregate  bob 3.16.10
2.0.4  script2  get_aggregate, get_pool tim 3.16.10
2.0.5  script2  get_aggregate, get_pool, make_volume paul 3.24.10
"""


# Split each line into words after splitting text into lines
tokens = [line.split() for line in text.splitlines()]

LINE = 10 * "*" # For prettier output.

# Use slicing syntax to get first two words [:2]
# All words except first two and last two [2:-2]
# Strip the comma from each word inside a comprehension
# Use slicing syntax to get last two words [-2:]
for (item, name), functions, (owner, date) in [
    (items[:2], [word.strip(",") for word in items[2:-2]], items[-2:])
    for items in tokens
]:
    for message in (
        f"The item, name are {(item, name)}",
        f"The functions are {functions}",
        f"The owner, date are {(owner, date)}",
        LINE,
    ):
        print(message)
```

OUTPUT:

```
The item, name are ('1.20.4.2', 'script1')
The functions are ['get_pool']
The owner, date are ('tim', '3.15.08')
**********
The item, name are ('1.20.5.1', 'script1')
The functions are ['get_aggregate']
The owner, date are ('bob', '3.16.10')
**********
The item, name are ('2.0.4', 'script2')
The functions are ['get_aggregate', 'get_pool']
The owner, date are ('tim', '3.16.10')
**********
The item, name are ('2.0.5', 'script2')
The functions are ['get_aggregate', 'get_pool', 'make_volume']
The owner, date are ('paul', '3.24.10')
**********
```